# For evolving slowly get better creatures or get lots of weak ones

Tags: fort-conquer

I am wondering how evolving algorithm works in the game. Does it pay of more to buy lots of weak creatures evolve them and then buy more of the weak creatures or will that end up costing more money than buying couple of more powerful creatures and evolving them that way.

What is the better strategy to get the best power/money ratio.

Answer (score -1):

Evolving in this game is something that you improve on with experience. As we all know, we are to select the creatures for the 3 different classes (range and body and speed), but in many occasions, we compromise, improving one spec whilst depleting another. It depends on what you solely need at that point in time, such as a long ranger that can kill a dragon without getting harmed.
You'll also see that the supposedly weak creatures when combined well with other creatures could be a grand asset.

Answer (score -2):

Keep upgrading the stope for the first 100 levels. Do not buy any powerful dragon or super evolve any of the creatures.